# How to change Windows User Account name throughout the system?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

Is it possible to change the Windows User Account name throughout the system?

Like the examples below, there may be other locations where there is no change in account name.

[image]

If yes, please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The two images you have included show both the same - the profile folder.

As Microsoft [says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path) :

> When you rename a user account [...], the user profile path is not
>   changed automatically. It may cause some confusion when the
>   `%SystemDrive%\users` folder is viewed

The article recommends this procedure :

1. Log-in as another admin account
2. Rename your `C:\Users\<user-name>` folder
3. Use `regedit` to go to the key
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.
4. Find your account as a sub-key. It can be identified by the
   `ProfileImagePath` item.
5. Modify the value of `ProfileImagePath` to the new path name
6. Log out and log in again by using the user whose name was changed

I suggest creating at least a system restore point as backup before starting.

A more detailed wiki of the procedure can be [found here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/19834.how-to-rename-a-windows-7-user-account-and-related-profile-folder.aspx) (although
written for Windows 7 and has more steps).

I don't know of other places where the old user-name may still be left.
You will have to deal with them when encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. Create another administrator account, as you seem to have only one
2. Log in with said new administrator account
3. Rename your user folder, so in your case `C:\Users\MyDesktop` to `C:\Users\Digital Machine`
4. With regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\`
5. Among the entries, identify your account using the `ProfileImagePath` key
6. Change said key, in your case to `C:\Users\Digital Machine`
7. Log out.

On your next login, your user account should use the updated user path.

Source: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path

Comment: I got there first by 6 whole minutes ....

Comment: @harrymc you beat me. Nice, I guess